# Select em xamarin forms, como seria?

Tags: xamarin-forms, selected-option

Estou criando um formulário de contato em xamarin, e deve ter uma opção para o usuário selecionar a finalidade desejada, ou seja, em html iria existir uma tag `select` com todas as `option`, portanto qual tags se usa para criar isso no xamarin?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Então, em uma pesquisa aqui na documentação **xamarin** eu encontrei o que é usado para substituir o `select` no **xamarin**, sendo assim um `select` com as `option` necessária ficaria dessa forma:

```
<Picker x:Name="pckFinalidade" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Title="Escolha a finalidade">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>CORREÇÃO DE ERRO</x:String>
                        <x:String>MELHORIA DE SISTEMA</x:String>
                        <x:String>NOVA FUNCIONALIDADE</x:String>
                        <x:String>NOVO RELATÓRIO/ETIQUETA</x:String>
                        <x:String>OBRIGAÇÕES FISCAIS</x:String>
                        <x:String>MIGRAÇÃO DE SISTEMA</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
```

Answer (score 2):

No `Android` e no `Xamarin.droid` é conhecido como `Spinner`, no `ios` não encontrei nada sobre.

Aqui tem uma discussão sobre o `Spinner` no `Forms`: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55637/how-to-use-spinner-in-xamarin-forms. Aqui uma lib pra implementar isso no `Forms` (que é sugerida na discussão acima): https://github.com/amccorma/xamarin-amccorma/tree/master/Forms.DropDown

Também há o `Picker` oficial da `Xamarin`, mas o design não parece muito legal (no `Android`, por exemplo, é usado um `AlertDialog` com as opções, e não um `Spinner` em si) https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/ (Tem imagens pra ver como é)